# laravel - response from controller start whit semicolon

Tags: php, laravel

this is my route:

```
Route::get('/auth/login', 'AuthenticationController@login');
```

and this is my controller:

```
class AuthenticationController extends BaseController {


public function login(){

    $credentials=Input::all();
    $userName = $credentials['userId'];
    $password = hash('sha256', $credentials['password']);

    return $userName;
```

Of course this procedure does not make sense, in fact I removed the logic of the procedure to make it more readable.

The problem is that, on every response from the server, a semicolon is appended at the beginning. Assuming that the user name is

> mark86

what the server return is:

> ;mark86

Also if I replace the return statement whit:

```
echo 'hi';
```

the server still returns:

> ;hi

hope someone could help me, thanks.

Comment: Can you oat your view for the login form as well?

Comment: It sounds like somewhere you are echoing a `;`.  try `echo 'hi'; exit;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks to me like you have a ";" out side of tags higher in your script.

(Because the print of shows the ";" First means it is higher in the script than the initial echo)

Comment: ;<?php - Sorry for the waste of time...I'm going to bury me :(

Comment: Nah it happens to the best of us, just remember php runs from top to bottom so if you see something in your out put that is a miss, higher it executes on the page the higher it will be in the script.